# commandline request to get ipv6 address as from test-ipv6.com

Tags: ipv6

https://test-ipv6.com gives me an ipv6 address as:

> "Your IPv6 address on the public Internet appears to be 2604:...."

How can I get that information through the commandline?

For IPv4 I can do this :

```
 wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain
```

and get the external IPv4 ip for my LAN

I want that service for IPv6. IPv6 is a different animal I *understand* but the notion of external access by host is still relevant.

I see that `test-ipv6.com` returns a different internet IPv6 address for each of my LAN-hosts' net devices **alternatively** there may be a way of getting that info from the output of each host. So:

```
 ip a | grep inet6
```

will list the IPv6 addresses associated with each network device but I don't know how to identify which one of those addresses is the address "on the public internet". Is there a universal rule, a pattern that identifies that address?

Comment: Any address starting with "::", "fc", "fd", or "fe" are unable to work with the public IPv6 Internet.

Comment: @user535733 So are all the others public? I don't find that. Could be a fluke?

Comment: This online version is pretty cool https://8gwifi.org/curlfunctions.jsp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this on a [gist](https://gist.github.com/yurrriq/7fc7634dd00494072f45)

```
curl -s ipv6.icanhazip.com
```